# Apache Beam: Skipping steps in an already-constructed pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a way to conditionally skip steps in an already-constructed pipeline? Or is pipeline construction designed to be the only way to control which steps are run?

Comment: Yes, if you're performing a transform on data and you don't `output` anything from the transform, subsequent pipeline steps won't be carried out for that data. See the answer here from @Anton (a Google developer who contributes on Apache Beam) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664636/apache-beam-skip-pipeline-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, pipeline construction controls what transformations in a pipeline will be executed.

You can, however, imagine a single input, multiple output `ParDo` that multiplexes the input `PCollection` to one of the output `PCollection`s. Then, by choosing which output to pass your data to, you can dynamically control which steps are executed -- steps without any input might not be executed and/or their execution might not matter.

A related feature is "parameterized pipelines" or "template pipelines". This is something we are very interested in and are actively working on.