# Skipping step in an apache beam pipeline Python

Tags: python, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

So I'm constructing an apache beam pipeline and having some trouble skipping the rest of the steps in the python SDK. Here is a simplified example I'm having trouble with:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import os 

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = API_KEY
def foo(message):
    pass

options = {
    'streaming': True
}

runner = 'DirectRunner'
opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
with beam.Pipeline(runner, options=opts) as p:
    sub_message = (p | 'sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=my_sub))
    result = (sub_message | 'foo' >> beam.Map(foo))
    result | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)

    job = p.run()
    if runner == 'DirectRunner':
        job.wait_until_finish()
```

So according to this: [Apache Beam - skip pipeline step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664636/apache-beam-skip-pipeline-step) which is in Java if my function doesn't return anything then apache_beam should skip the rest of the steps. Correct me if I'm wrong but in python that is the same as returning None so my `pass` could be replaced with `return None` and be the exact same. But when I run this code with the `pass` or `return None` the result does end up going to the next step. That is, it keeps printing `None` when it should not be printing anything since it should skip all of the next steps. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough, as soon as I posted this I found the answer out on the docs. So looks like in the link I provided the equivalent is using a ParDo NOT a map as I did. So really it should look like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import os 

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials
class TestFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print('hi')
        pass

options = {
    'streaming': True
}

runner = 'DirectRunner'
opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
with beam.Pipeline(runner, options=opts) as p:
    sub_message = (p | 'sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=mysub))
    result = (sub_message | 'foo' >> beam.ParDo(TestFn()))
    result | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)

    job = p.run()
    if runner == 'DirectRunner':
        job.wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: Note that using p in a context automatically calls `p.run().wait_until_finish()`, so this may end up submitting your pipeline twice.